# more that 250+ connection open in mysql getting strange issue in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am working on zend framework, I can see when i load the because it is getting lots of time to load, and in mysql database there are more than 250+ connections open, I am using zend 1 framework,  can anyone please help me what we can do to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated

Comment: I don't think Zend 1 supports connection pooling

Answer (score 0):

Those 250+ connection, are in production environment or in test?
How many user that make requests do you have?
Are you using Db or multiDb resource?
Does your html pages make async requests once loaded?

There are lots of variables to keep in consideration to debug this issue